# Error with Bundler Commands in Specific Directory on Windows: NoMethodError for 'untaint' Method in Ruby 3.3.0

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, bundler, nomethoderror

I've encountered an issue while trying to install `ltx2any` by following the instructions provided on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any/wiki). I am not very familiar with Ruby, and I installed it using Chocolatey on Windows. I then installed Bundler using the `gem install bundler` command.

When I run `bundler -v` in any directory other than the cloned `ltx2any` directory, I get the correct output showing `Bundler version 2.5.5`. However, when I try to run any bundler command in the cloned `ltx2any` directory, I receive the following error message:

```
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:266:in `search_up': undefined method `untaint' for an instance of String (NoMethodError)

      current  = File.expand_path(SharedHelpers.pwd).untaint
                                                    ^^^^^^^^
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:253:in `find_file'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:245:in `find_gemfile'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:27:in `root'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:218:in `root'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:230:in `app_config_path'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:257:in `settings'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/env.rb:20:in `report'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:96:in `request_issue_report_for'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:46:in `log_error'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:126:in `rescue in with_friendly_errors'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundler:4:in `load'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundler:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/bin/bundler:32:in `load'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/bin/bundler:32:in `<main>'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:266:in `search_up': undefined method `untaint' for an instance of String (NoMethodError)

      current  = File.expand_path(SharedHelpers.pwd).untaint
                                                    ^^^^^^^^
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:253:in `find_file'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:245:in `find_gemfile'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:27:in `root'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:218:in `root'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:230:in `app_config_path'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:257:in `settings'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/feature_flag.rb:21:in `block in settings_method'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:97:in `<class:CLI>'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:7:in `<module:Bundler>'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:122:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundler:4:in `load'
        from C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundler:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/bin/bundler:32:in `load'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/bin/bundler:32:in `<main>'
```

This error seems to be related to the `untaint` method, which I understand has been removed in Ruby 3.2 and later. However, I'm not sure why it's attempting to use Bundler 1.16.1 in the `ltx2any` directory despite having Bundler 2.5.5 installed.

Here are the things I have tried so far:

- updating Bundler using `gem install bundler`
- the `bundler update` command, however, fails with the same error message as above
- ran `gem update --system` multiple times
- deleted and recloned the project folder

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Specifically, I'm looking to understand:

- Why Bundler reverts to an older version in the specific directory.
- How do you ensure that Bundler 2.5.5 is used across all directories?
- Any steps required to fix this issue and successfully install ltx2any.

**P.S.** I posted a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77869729/4999991).

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of bundler remember the bundler version that was used to create the `Gemfile.lock`. It will then install and use this exact version for all future invocations with this Gemfile.lock.

You can refer to the announcement blog post for this feature at [Bundler v2.3: Locking the version of Bundler itself](https://bundler.io/blog/2022/01/23/bundler-v2-3.html) for details how this works.

To use the latest bundler version with your `Gemfile.lock`, you likely want to run `bundle update --bundler` accordingly. Afterwards, you can run `bundle install` again to install the gems from your `Gemfile` / `Gemfile.lock` using the update Bundler version.

Comment: Now I get the error message `An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.25), and Bundler cannot continue.`

Comment: The complete error message is [here](https://pastebin.com/YYqamvhs).

Comment: posted a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77869729/4999991)