# Ruby ffi Gem Installation Fails on Windows Even After Installing Ruby with DevKit and mingw-w64-x86_64-libffi via MSYS2

Tags: ruby, windows, bundler, ffi, msys2

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77869461/4999991) I  encountered an issue while running `bundle update --bundler`. The process failed due to an error with the ffi gem installation.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching ffi 1.9.25
Fetching json 2.6.3
Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Fetching parallel 1.12.1
Fetching ruby-progressbar 1.10.0
Installing parallel 1.12.1
Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Installing json 2.6.3 with native extensions
Installing ffi 1.9.25 with native extensions
Installing ruby-progressbar 1.10.0
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c
C:/tools/ruby33/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for pkg-config for libffi... not found
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --without-opt-include
        --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --without-opt-lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/tools/ruby33/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-ffi_c-dir
        --without-ffi_c-dir
        --with-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
        --without-ffi_c-include
        --with-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
        --without-ffi_c-lib
        --with-libffi-dir
        --without-libffi-dir
        --with-libffi-include=${libffi-dir}/include
        --without-libffi-include
        --with-libffi-lib=${libffi-dir}/lib
        --without-libffi-lib
        --with-libffi-config
        --without-libffi-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-ffi-dir
        --without-ffi-dir
        --with-ffi-include=${ffi-dir}/include
        --without-ffi-include
        --with-ffi-lib=${ffi-dir}/lib
        --without-ffi-lib
C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:480:in `try_do': The compiler failed to
generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.

        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:606:in `block in try_compile'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:555:in `with_werror'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:606:in `try_compile'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:1151:in `block in have_header'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:983:in `block in checking_for'
from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:344:in `block (2 levels) in
postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:314:in `open'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:344:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:314:in `open'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:982:in `checking_for'
        from C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:1150:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/ffi-1.9.25/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/ffi-1.9.25/gem_make.out

  C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:125:in `run'
C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:28:in
`build'
C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:193:in
`build_extension'
C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:227:in `block
in build_extensions'
  C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:224:in `each'
C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:224:in
`build_extensions'
C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:852:in
`build_extensions'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:76:in
`build_extensions'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:205:in
`install'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:132:in
`do_install'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:123:in
`block in worker_pool'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
`apply_func'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in
`block in process_queue'
  :187:in `loop'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`process_queue'
C:/Users/FooBar/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in
`block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.25), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  listen was resolved to 3.8.0, which depends on
    rb-inotify was resolved to 0.9.10, which depends on
      ffi
```

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. Initially, I tried running `bundle update --bundler`, but it failed due to an ffi installation error.
2. Suspecting that I might need the Ruby Development Kit (DevKit), I uninstalled my existing Ruby installation. Since the Chocolatey package for DevKit was [deprecated](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/ruby2.devkit#comment-6373920770), I opted for "Ruby 3.2 with MSYS2 RubyInstallerTeam.RubyWithDevKit.3.2 3.2.2-1 Tag: ruby winget" using winget.
3. Next, I installed `mingw-w64-x86_64-libffi` using `ucrt64.exe` run as administrator.
4. After this setup, running `gem install ffi --platform=ruby` worked successfully.

However, I am still facing issues with other dependencies. The `ffi` gem installation seems correct but doesn't resolve the overall bundler update failure.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/0FzPAX9Q)'s a snippet of the error log.

I am seeking guidance on setting up my environment to resolve these issues properly. Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong or what additional steps should be taken would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the winget suggestion. That worked.